# Remove an assembly from an application domain

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-assembly, appdomain

So I'm trying to remove an assembly from my 
`Thread.GetDomain().GetAssemblies()`
area.

I've looked at a couple of explanations on the web so far but have just not been able to figure it out.

This is what I've gotten so far

```
AppDomain tempD = Thread.GetDomain();
tempD.DoCallBack(LoaderCallback);
AppDomain.Unload(tempD);
System.IO.File.Delete(assemblyName);

private static void LoaderCallback()
{
     Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("myAssembly");

     //byte[] raw = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(test);
     //Assembly yacsi = Assembly.Load(raw);
     //((IScript)yacsi.CreateInstance("Script")).Go();
}
```

I've played around with this concept so far but I'm struggling to make the connection because  `Thread.GetDomain();` does not contain the `Unload` command

Also I wasn't able to try this part `((IScript)yacsi.CreateInstance("Script")).Go()` because I don't know what assembly IScript is nor what to place in the  "Script" text section

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: There's no such thing as a Thread Domain.  From MSDN: *There is no way to unload an individual assembly without unloading all of the application domains that contain it. Use the Unload method from AppDomain to unload the application domains. For more information, see [Unloading an Application Domain.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5b8a8f9(v=vs.80).aspx)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add on top @RobertHarvey's comment and also take a step back, what you want to do is create a separate `AppDomain` and load your assembly into it. 
After that you can marshal into your domain various types you intend to use.

When you're done with them, you can unload the application domain, thus getting rid of the assembly.

You should note that inter-domain instance marshaling is done through .NET Remoting, so you may want to play with the [remoting lease policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.lifetime.lifetimeservices.aspx) which include, among other things, time values for a marshaled object's lifetime. The reason for modifying lease duration is that a marshaled instance expires after a predefined period of time, if it's not called/used at all. So, you may want to avoid re-marshaling instances over and over again and just prolong their lifetime in your domain.

I think [this is a good sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42312/Loading-Assemblies-in-Separate-Directories-Into-a) showing how you can load an assembly into a new `AppDomain` and also unload it. Lots of other samples out there.

As long as you know what the process should be, finding code for it is straightforward.